# Solve systemtap (stap) "Spawn error (2): No such file or directory"

Tags: systemtap

Running a previously working stap script I now get:

```
$ sudo PATH=$MORE_PATH_ENTRIES stap -v myscript.stp
...blahblah...
Pass 4: compilation failed.  [man error::pass4]
```

with `-vvv` the output includes:

```
Running env -uARCH -uKBUILD_EXTMOD -uCROSS_COMPILE -uKBUILD_IMAGE -uKCONFIG_CONFIG -uINSTALL_PATH -uLD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/home/craig/pg/2Qpg11/bin:/home/craig/pg/2Qpg11/lib:/home/craig/pg/2Qpg11/lib/postgresql make -C /lib/modules/5.3.5-200.fc30.x86_64/build M=/tmp/stapRYZTEG modules CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO= CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION= ARCH=x86_64 V=1 -j3
Spawn error (2): No such file or directory
Pass 4: compiled C into "stap_7c7a2de666aeb2fcb103c8fd5f66282b_105914.ko" in 0usr/0sys/0real ms.
Pass 4: compilation failed.  [man error::pass4]
Running rm -rf /tmp/stap7h4EmH
Spawn error (2): No such file or directory
Removed temporary directory "/tmp/stap7h4EmH"
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` change caused `stap` to be unable to find the tools it requires - there's no `:$PATH` on the end to append the old `PATH`.

Wrong:

```
$ sudo PATH=$MORE_PATH_ENTRIES stap -v myscript.stp
```

Right (if you trust the current `PATH`):

```
$ sudo PATH=$MORE_PATH_ENTRIES:$PATH stap -v myscript.stp
```

In general if you see this error you should check your `PATH`, ensure `make` can be found, etc.

Posting here because it took me *way* too long to work it out, due mainly to the useless error messages.